# Initialize ViewController in iOS 7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, viewdidload

I used to initialize my `UIViewController` in `- (void) viewDidLoad`.

Since the update to iOS 7 the viewDidLoad method is either not called or after executing `setItemAndParents`.

Example:

I have a `UITableViewController` if you click on a cell the desired view is loaded:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // some more code
    [cpvc setItemAndParents:items[selectedIndex] orderIndex:indexOrder];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    cpvc = segue.destinationViewController;
}
```

Where am I supposed to initialize the ViewController.

Remember with iOS 6 everything worked find.

Comment: Can you verify that "`cpvc`" is nil when you click on a table cell?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it's not nil - else I would get a nil/null pointer exception - isn't it?? Don't understand your question anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup it happens to me also... You can initialized view controller in - (void)awakeFromNib{} method. This method help me in the same scenario as you have.

Comment: Great - now I initialize my variables in -(void)awakeFromNib and the GUI elements in viewDidLoad :)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem.

I inserted this right after allocation of viewController (or in some case after pushViewController):

viewController.view.hidden = NO;

and it calls viewDidLoad.

Hope I helped.

Comment: This is working because as soon as you ask for 'view' property, the controller loads it and viewDidLoad is called